# Apache URL rewriting not working

Tags: htaccess, apache, url-rewriting

All `.php` files are rewritted before doing the below rewriting:

```
test.php => test
foo.php => foo
```

I want to rewrite this URL `http://www.testdomain.com/test?name=john&id=2&nick=doe` to `http://www.testdomain.com/test/john/2/doe`.

`test` is the index file.

I tried these methods to rewrite:

1. Method 1:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ test?name=$1&id=$2&nick=$3 [L,QSA]
   ```
2. Method 2:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ test.php?name=$1&id=$2&nick=$3 [L,QSA]
   ```
3. Method 3:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /test?name=$1&id=$2&nick=$3 [L]
   ```

**updated .htaccess file**
content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([\w]+)\&id=([\d]{1,3})\&nick=([\w]+)$
RewriteRule .* /test/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

All of them are not working (URL remains the same they don't take effect)! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "not working" - in what way "not working"? Incorrect rewrite? Rewrite loop? "All php files are **rewritted** before doing the below rewriting" - I assume you mean "redirected"? This could be the problem and could be resulting in a rewrite loop - can you paste your entire .htaccess file. You also probably want to be rewriting to a root-relative URL, rather than a relative URL. ie. `/test.php?...`, not `test.php?...`. #2 would seem to be the closest to "correct".

Comment: @w3d see the edit

Comment: are you sure that server is parsing your .htaccess at all? Sometimes you can only set it in apache configuration.

Comment: @edvinas.me yeah of course it's parsing the URL rewrite because .php is removed from every php file when a php file is accessed !!!

Comment: We can not work out a reliable rule without knowing what you have in your .htaccess file, so any answer is going to start from http://www.testdomain.com/test.php?name=john&id=2&nick=doe which may or may not suit you. The only way for you to get a good answer is to post here your .htaccess file or use the whole rewrite that somebody writes.

Comment: @PatomaS i already posted the .htaccess content at last . that's all i have in my .htaccess file.

Comment: @PatomaS also i deleted all the content from .htaccess and pasted only test rewrite rule but still it doesn't work

Comment: In you question you state that two options are valid if that is not what you want, change your question accordingly.

Comment: My small advice, and my knowledge says to do all of your URL rerouting within PHP itself, which is coming more and more popular with the release of PHP5. For me it is easier to do than trying to force .HTAccess to rewrite URLs now.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that two options are valid for you, so I'm using the second one, `http://www.testdomain.com/john/2/doe`, and assuming a clean .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([\w]+)\&id=([\d]{1,3})\&nick=([\w]+)$
RewriteRule .* /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

The commented lines that check for files or directories may be uncommented depending on your situation, lets assume that a request on your site is going to be like this

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?name=john&id=2&nick=doe
```

If you have the file `test.php` and you uncomment the line about checking for existing files, the rule I wrote will fail because of unmet conditions. If you don't have that file, you can uncomment the line. The same applies for directories, although safer since I don't think you have directories with extensions.

The above rules transform

```
http://www.example.com/test?name=john&id=2&nick=doe
```

into

```
http://www.example.com/john/2/doe
```

I tested it on a virtual server with Apache 2.2.25 on Linux.

Below is the rewrite log of the test in case you want to analyse it. The name of the folder and local virtual server where different, I hope I didn't alter anything important when renaming that information.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164002970/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] strip per-dir prefix: /mnt/webs/folder/test.php -> test.php
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164002970/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'test.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164002970/initial] (2) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] rewrite 'test.php' -> '/john/2/doe?'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164002970/initial] (3) split uri=/john/2/doe? -> uri=/john/2/doe, args=<none>
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164002970/initial] (2) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.example.com/john/2/doe
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164002970/initial] (1) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] escaping http://www.example.com/john/2/doe for redirect
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164002970/initial] (1) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] redirect to http://www.example.com/john/2/doe [REDIRECT/301]
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164006990/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] add path info postfix: /mnt/webs/folder/john -> /mnt/webs/folder/john/2/doe
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164006990/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] strip per-dir prefix: /mnt/webs/folder/john/2/doe -> john/2/doe
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164006990/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'john/2/doe'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014:00:03:50 +0800] [www.example.com/sid#cee650][rid#7fe164006990/initial] (1) [perdir /mnt/webs/folder/] pass through /mnt/webs/folder/john
```

**Update according to your comment**
If you want test on the final URL, use this:

```
RewriteRule .* /test/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

If you want your index file, use this:

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works no problem but i want **test** or any other file name in my url. is there a way to do that ?

Comment: A random word can not be there, if you want test, I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: now i am getting this error "The requested URL /test/alex/1/ax.php was not found on this server." apache appending .php to the last parameter. i don't know why apache is doing this .

Comment: url rewriting is working but apache appending .php

Comment: check the update .htaccess this is happening after i remove .php from all files

Answer (score 0):

You should just redirect everything  to your script then process in there like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

So then you can explode the `$_GET['url']` by `/` to get the individual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar rule, try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ test.php?name=$1&id=$2&nick=$3
```

Your links should be:

```
test.php?name=john&id=2&nick=doe
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "Method 2" looks appropriate to me to match `http://www.testdomain.com/john/2/doe`.

Only, you may want to try to add the `RewriteBase /` too, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ test.php?name=$1&id=$2&nick=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Instead of the base, you could try adding a slash at the start of the regex:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ test.php?name=$1&id=$2&nick=$3 [L,QSA]
#            ^--- this slash
```

You may also want to be careful with the QSA flag since other query string parameters will be kept in that way.

Note that rewriting to `test.php` as is means that this PHP program is in the same directory as your **.htaccess** file. If it is not there, then the rewrite may not take place because the mod_rewrite module detects the missing entry and thus bypasses the rule automatically. If that's the case, it should appear in your error logs. Otherwise you may need to put a path in front of the test.php script name.

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /test.php?name=$1&id=$2&nick=$3 [L,QSA]
#            ^--- those slashes  ---^
```

Note that we may need to get a copy of your access and error logs to see whether Apache actually tells you what's wrong. You may want/need to increase the verbosity to get more info.

---

P.S. This paragraph seems to be reversed... maybe you could edit your question and fix it?

> I want to rewrite this URL `http://www.testdomain.com/test?name=john&id=2&nick=doe` to `http://www.testdomain.com/test/john/2/doe` or `http://www.testdomain.com/john/2/doe`.

Answer (score -2):

Use linux hosting. May be your hosting server is on windows. Windows gives problems sometimes with htaccess.

Comment: Can you provide links to sources that backs up your assertion that Windows hosts don't support htaccess well enough for this?   As it stands, this is a very low quality answer.

Comment: I had a problem like it. CHanged to linux and solved!